# Is there a way to store global variable values using User Defaults? SwiftUI

Tags: global-variables, swiftui

I have to have the global variables because of the way I built the app. Is it possible to use User Defaults to store global variables on SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserDefaults.standard.set(myGlobal, forKey: "com.myself.myglobalkey")